Teams and Sharepoint Reporting query in regards to Channels
Is it Possible to run a report that will show me the Size In storage quota that each Channel is set to across the whole of the estate of teams sites
Thanks in advance
i have been running the various reports that are available in M365 Admin but am yet to come across one that gives me what i need specifically for the above.

Welcome to SO. What did you try so far? Please share your piece of code.

Sorry not tried any code based reporting as yet just what was available to me in Sharegate and M365 admin itself neither seem to have funtion to report on Just Channels Sizes

Please understand that you have to give more context to this question. Kindly edit the question and explain where you need the storage quota. If it is sharepoint directly, then Get-SPOGeoStorageQuota would help you. But this is just one google search. So kindly share your efforts so that we could help you better

Please provide enough code so others can better understand or reproduce the problem.
